# Segmentation fault with two pointers

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I don't get why, if I remove the comments from the piece of code below, I get a segmentation fault.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int var = 9;
    int *ptr;
    *ptr = 20;
    int *ptrD;
    *ptrD = 26;

    printf("var %d\n", var);
    printf("*ptr %d\n", *ptr);
    printf("*ptrD %d\n", *ptrD);

    *ptr = 18;
    printf("*ptr %d\n", *ptr);
    *ptrD = 24;
    printf("*ptrD %d\n", *ptrD);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `ptr` is uninitialized, which leads to *undefined behaviour*. Segementation fault is a possible outcome. Don't do that!

Comment: @l3x Why not post this as an answer to the question? If you know how to fix the problem, that's even better!

Comment: There are no comments in the code below.

Comment: @underscore_d I request you to be double-sure of you comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These pointers are *uninitialized* and you dereference them which will eventually lead to *undefined behaviour*.

These statements -

```
 printf("*ptrD %d\n", *ptrD);
 ...
 *ptrD = 26;
 printf("*ptrD %d\n", *ptrD);
```

One of possible way to get work -

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
   int var = 9;  
   int *ptr=&var;                   // ptr points to var
   int *ptrD=&var;                  // ptrD points to var
   /* both the pointers now have the address of variable var    */
   printf("var %d\n", var);
   printf("*ptrD %d\n", *ptrD);
   *ptrD = 26;                      // change value at address pointed by ptrD
   /*  this will change the value of the var , i.e now var is 26 */
   printf("*ptrD %d\n", *ptrD);  
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use the heap

Comment: So what **do** you want to do? Or are you just writing random code for the fun of it, then complaining when it doesn't pick something cool to do?

Answer (score 3):

In your code,

```
 printf("*ptrD %d\n", *ptrD);
```

`ptrD` is uninitialized and it points to some random location. Effect: [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Same goes for

```
*ptrD = 26;
printf("*ptrD %d\n", *ptrD);
```

too.

***Maybe*** you wanted, (*but missed*)

```
ptrD = &var;
```

as the very next statement after the definitions.

*[P.S - You should be thankful that due to the UB, the application did not use your credit card to order pizza and pony for all your colleagues. Jokes apart, Once you hit UB, nothing, absolutely nothing is guaranteed.]*

Comment: that doesn't seem to be the problem

Answer (score 1):

You should get a segmentation fault in this code too..

You are accessing pointers without allocating memory to it

```
//printf("*ptr %d\n", *ptr);
printf("*ptrD %d\n", *ptrD);
```

`*ptrD` has not been allocated memory, so its uninitialized, and is pointing to random memory address. Accessing that is giving you the segmentation fault.